# Representing blank spaces in an array or Adding a Holder for blank spaces in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, spaces

I have an array of elements (list of names) and their votes.  So if a person is present and voted it will show next to the person’s name a Y, N, A.  But when the person is not present and therefore did not vote it shows a blank.  I wanted to know how to represent the blank field in the array.
Because what happens is that, when reading the array (let’s say for John it will assign Y, N, Y, Y and it will fill the blank spots).  I want a holder for the blank spots so that it will read   Y,   N,       ,
,     Y,   Y. And still be able to see the blank spaces.  Thanks.
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `null` value which is different of `undefined`.

A basic code example :

```
list = [
  { name: "Jessica", votes: ['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', null, 'A'] }
  /* ... */
];

for (let people of list)
{
   for (let vote of people.votes)
   {
      if (vote === null) console.log(`${people.name} was not present`);
      else console.log(`${people.name} vote ${vote}`);
   }
}
```

Think to use triple `===` to compare, so `undefined`, `null`, `0` and `false` are distinct.